# Installing Visual Studio 2010 AFTER Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I had Visual Studio 2012 installed on my new development computer and it worked fine. Without thinking I then installed VS2010 onto the computer which already had the 2012 install. 2012 continues to work correctly but 2010 cannot compile any of my previous working source code and it seems unable to locate any of the correct libraries.

For instance in a simple C++ hello world program I get the following error

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
```

I have tried un-installing both, installing 2010 first then 2012 but the same problems still occur. I have also made sure it is using platform toolkit v100 but it seems to make no difference.

I have also tried repairing VS2010 to no avail.

Has anyone else experienced the same issues and if so how did they manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it has something to do with VS2012's new v110_xp platform toolset which uses an SDK similar to 7.1.  For my older projects that need 2003 Server and XP support I use that toolset now with VS2012 instead of the default toolset with VS2008 or VS2010 so I no longer need the older Visual Studios.  It might solve your problem as well.

Comment: Soo, what should the OP do to use this new toolset?

Comment: assuming VS is up to date: Project->Properties->General->Platform Toolset->v110_xp